# Applying lm() and predict() to multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I have an example dataset below.

```
train<-data.frame(x1 = c(4,5,6,4,3,5), x2 = c(4,2,4,0,5,4), x3 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1),
                  x4 = c(1,0,1,1,0,0), x5 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1))
```

Suppose I want to create separate models for column `x3`, `x4`, `x5` based on column `x1` and `x2`. For example

```
lm1 <- lm(x3 ~ x1 + x2)
lm2 <- lm(x4 ~ x1 + x2)
lm3 <- lm(x5 ~ x1 + x2)
```

I want to then take these models and apply them to a testing set using predict, and then create a matrix that has each model outcome as a column.

```
test <- data.frame(x1 = c(4,3,2,1,5,6), x2 = c(4,2,1,6,8,5))
p1 <- predict(lm1, newdata = test)
p2 <- predict(lm2, newdata = test)
p3 <- predict(lm3, newdata = test)
final <- cbind(p1, p2, p3)
```

This is a simplified version where you can do it step by step, the actual data is far too large. Is there a way to create a function or use a for statement to combine this into one or two steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had an inclination to close your question as a duplicate to [Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262534/4891738), but sadly the prediction issue is not addressed over there. On the other hand, [Prediction of 'mlm' linear model object from `lm()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39553770/4891738) talks about prediction, but is a little bit far off your situation, as you work with formula interface instead of matrix interface.

I did not manage to locate a perfect duplicate target in ["mlm" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mlm). So I think it a good idea to contribute another answer for this tag. As I said in linked questions, `predict.mlm` does not support `se.fit`, and at the moment, this is also a missing issue in "mlm" tag. So I would take this chance to fill such gap.

---

Here is a function to get standard error of prediction:

```
f <- function (mlmObject, newdata) {
  ## model formula
  form <- formula(mlmObject)
  ## drop response (LHS)
  form[[2]] <- NULL
  ## prediction matrix
  X <- model.matrix(form, newdata)
  Q <- forwardsolve(t(qr.R(mlmObject$qr)), t(X))
  ## unscaled prediction standard error
  unscaled.se <- sqrt(colSums(Q ^ 2))
  ## residual standard error
  sigma <- sqrt(colSums(residuals(mlmObject) ^ 2) / mlmObject$df.residual)
  ## scaled prediction standard error
  tcrossprod(unscaled.se, sigma)
  }
```

For your given example, you can do

```
## fit an `mlm`
fit <- lm(cbind(x3, x4, x5) ~ x1 + x2, data = train)

## prediction (mean only)
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = test)

#            x3          x4         x5
#1  0.555956679  0.38628159 0.60649819
#2  0.003610108  0.47653430 0.95848375
#3 -0.458483755  0.48014440 1.27256318
#4 -0.379061372 -0.03610108 1.35920578
#5  1.288808664  0.12274368 0.17870036
#6  1.389891697  0.46570397 0.01624549

## prediction error
pred.se <- f(fit, newdata = test)

#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.1974039 0.3321300 0.2976205
#[2,] 0.3254108 0.5475000 0.4906129
#[3,] 0.5071956 0.8533510 0.7646849
#[4,] 0.6583707 1.1077014 0.9926075
#[5,] 0.5049637 0.8495959 0.7613200
#[6,] 0.3552794 0.5977537 0.5356451
```

We can verify that `f` is correct:

```
## `lm1`, `lm2` and `lm3` are defined in your question
predict(lm1, test, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
#        1         2         3         4         5         6 
#0.1974039 0.3254108 0.5071956 0.6583707 0.5049637 0.3552794 

predict(lm2, test, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
#        1         2         3         4         5         6 
#0.3321300 0.5475000 0.8533510 1.1077014 0.8495959 0.5977537 

predict(lm3, test, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
#        1         2         3         4         5         6 
#0.2976205 0.4906129 0.7646849 0.9926075 0.7613200 0.5356451
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. To add on, what if I were to use another model say glmnet, what could I use for the 'y' value. I tried the above, but that form is not accepted.